# Watson Speech to Text request using Websockets and JAVA

Tags: java

I am trying to request a transcription of an MP3 file using Websockets and Java. The following is a snippet of my Maven dependency followed by the java code . I've put breakpoints in each of the Override methods but not hitting any of them. What am I doing wrong?

Maven Dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Code:

```
    SpeechToText speechToText = new SpeechToText();
    speechToText.setEndPoint("https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize");
    speechToText.setUsernameAndPassword("{myUsername}", "{myPassword}");

    try {
        RecognizeOptions recognizeOptions = new RecognizeOptions.Builder()
                .audio(new FileInputStream("KATL-App-Final-All-Aug-01-2017-1630.mp3-edited.mp3"))
                .contentType("audio/mp3")
                .model("en-US_NarrowbandModel")
                .interimResults(true)
                .build();

        BaseRecognizeCallback baseRecognizeCallback
                = new BaseRecognizeCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onListening() {
                System.out.println("Listening");
            }

            @Override
            public void onConnected() {
                System.out.println("Connected");
            }

            @Override
            public void onTranscription(SpeechRecognitionResults speechRecognitionResults) {
                System.out.println(speechRecognitionResults);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDisconnected() {
                System.exit(0);
            }

        };

        speechToText.recognizeUsingWebSocket(recognizeOptions,
                baseRecognizeCallback);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (;;) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure there's not an issue with the websocket? You haven't overridden every method in the `RecongnizeOptions` interface, namely `onError(Exception e)` which logs if the websocket fails... [BaseRecognizeCallback](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/blob/develop/speech-to-text/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/developer_cloud/speech_to_text/v1/websocket/BaseRecognizeCallback.java) / [RecognizeCallback](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/blob/develop/speech-to-text/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/developer_cloud/speech_to_text/v1/websocket/RecognizeCallback.java)

Comment: I added the onError method and I got back: Expected HTTP 101 response but was '401 Not Authorized'. I'm not sure why because I can issue a "curl" command with a successful response.
curl -X POST -u <myUserID>:<myPassword> --header "Content-Type: audio/mp3" --data-binary @KATL-App-Final-All-Aug-01-2017-1630.mp3-edited.mp3 "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?model=en-US_NarrowbandModel"

Answer (score 0):

I think I have identified the problem, which is your end point.

The `SpeechToText.recognizeUsingWebSocket()` method contains this helpful(?) line of code:

`HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse(getEndPoint() + "/v1/recognize").newBuilder();`

---

So try changing the end point to `https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api` or better yet don't set it and just construct `SpeechToText` using the constructor:

`SpeechToText(String username, String password)`

This will remove the need to invoke `setUsernameAndPassword()` and use the default end point:

`private static final String URL = "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api";`

Comment: I found my error. I took out the brackets ("{}") in the username and password. It now works. Thanks for your help.